# jQuery onclick event not working upon making multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am making few ajax requests in my jQuery file. On success of these jQuery requests, I wrote few on click events which are not working.

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'myServlet',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        id = parseInt(response);
        setOutputEvents();
    }
});

function setOutputEvents() {
    for (var queryNumber = 0; queryNumber <= id; queryNumber++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'myOtherServlet',
            data: {queryNumber: queryNumber},
            success: success,
            async: false
        });

        var success = function (response) { 
            //some code here
                generateTable();
        }
    }
}

function generateTable () {
    //some code here
    pagination();
}

function pagination(){
    $(".class").click(function(event) {
        alert();
    });
}

$("#me").on("click", function(){
    alert("me is triggered");
});
});
```

I understand making multiple ajax requests is a bad programming practice but what could be the reason for on click events not getting triggered?

These are the onclick events which are not working.

```
function pagination(){
    $(".class").click(function(event) {
        alert();
    });
}

$("#me").on("click", function(){
    alert("me is triggered");
});
```

I am using Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 on Windows 7.

Please do let me know if any further information is necessary.

Comment: Also using async:false is defeating the purpose of Ajax

Comment: using `function success(){...}` would work but doesn't make sense to set it inside loop and anyway i have personnaly hard time to understand your code logic regarding binding multiple times same events

Comment: @mplungjan I am using ajax request for just making query to the servlet. I don't need the asynchronous behavior of ajax.

Comment: @A.Wolff I am just giving this a try. I understand this approach would be slow but my problem is a something else.

Comment: I think the problem gets solved by making the execution of on click event to wait until the complete DOM is ready. i.e. until generateTable()  function is executed completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use ajax to load even the initial content it seems, .class / #me html elements likely do not exist on initial page load of the DOM.  As you didn't post html, i'm guessing this is the case.

Thus, you need to use a delegated event click handler to respond to it

so, you would change

```
 $("#me").on("click", function(){
```

to

```
 $(document).on("click", "#me", function(){
```

and so forth to link it to the parent element that does exist, the document itself.

Comment: `$("document")` returns empty object

Comment: Beware as OP is using synchronous requests, it shouldn't anyway be a delegation of click event issue, as i can read it

Comment: As I see it, (which of course may be incorrect) since the sync call is contained within the DOM-ready caller, the DOM is already built and registered before those html items come in from the servlet call.  Thus, a delegated event is the way to listen to those clicks.  No?

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#me", function(){` Unfortunately this did not work!

Comment: @briansol My DOM is complete only after generateTable() function is complete. So my onclick events should be executed only after generateTable function is executed.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#me", function(){` is working when run it from the console but not while executing it from the script.

Comment: @briansol Doesn't `$(document).on("click"....{` mean --> do click when all the DOM from the HTML is loaded? Whereas I am building my DOM from the js.

Comment: Don't confuse `DOM ready` with `DOM Complete`.  `document ready` will fire when all the elements are in place, and they can be referenced in the JS code, but the content is not necessarily loaded.  So, this is what you have for raw server-side output before any JS fires.   (#me is not here).  THEN, your servlet fires, and UPDATES the DOM with #me and other html.  Thus, in order to attach an event to it, it needs the delegated event listener attached to something that is loaded at initial DOM ready, in this case, `$(document)` is what you have to hook on.

Comment: If should be noted too that the system will never generate a `click`.  You are calling a function that has a click handler in it.   That will never fire.   As Taha's answer below explains, you need to fake it by invoking the `trigger` of the click so that the system can perform a "click"  and then the handler will respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
$(".class").on("click", function(){
    alert("me is triggered");
});

function generateTable () {
    //some code here
    pagination();
}

function pagination(){
    $(".class").trigger("click");
}
```

Some notes:

1. Event handler must be registered before triggering click.
2. Triggered click selector must match the class which has the click event registered.
3. Functions must be defined before the usage.